# Can a Fortran derived type have components from different modules?

Tags: module, fortran, derived-types

I am developing a derived type.  It keeps growing and is making the module in which it resides unwieldy.  Is there a way to break up the module into multiple modules and have the derived type obtain its components from the various modules?

Comment: There is nothing like a derived type element. Did you mean component? Did you consider type extension (inheritance)? Did you consider question your program design if it leads to such beasts?

Comment: @VladimirF Meant component.  Corrected.

Comment: Yes `use moda, only: a; type t; type(a) x; end type; end` is possible.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: It's not always a popular choice, but you could consider using `include` if your file is getting larger than you'd like. And although I don't have much experience with them, submodules might be another improvement/alternative.

Comment: I have ~40k lines, and have structure and constants in one meddle, functions in another, and subroutines in a few others... with them all in a library. The main programs import what is needed. Breaking the functions away from the subroutine resulted in significantly faster compile times, and most of the modification happen in the subroutines module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @francescalus points out, you can use derived types from other modules to
create new derived types. I think his example was a little short, so I wrote a
small example which I hope will give you an idea of how something like this
could work. Perhaps the example is longer than strictly necessary, but I was
enjoying myself.

My derived type describes travel plans, consisting of luggage and an itinerary.
It comes with a subroutine that will print a given travel plan.

```
module travel
use Luggage
use Routing
   type tTravel
       type(tItinerary) :: trip
       type(tSuitcase)  :: suitcase
   end type tTravel
contains
   subroutine printTravel(travel)
   implicit none
       type(tTravel), intent(in) :: travel
       print '(a)','    Luggage:'
       call printSuitcase(travel%suitcase)
       print '(a)','    Itinerary:'
       call printItinerary(travel%trip)
   end subroutine printTravel
end module travel
```

The two components of the travel plans, luggage and itinerary, each have their own
module. First, the Luggage-module:

```
module Luggage
   type tSuitcase
       integer :: socks = 2
       integer :: shirts = 1
       integer :: underwear = 1
       integer :: raincoats = 0
   end type tSuitcase
contains
   subroutine printSuitcase(suitcase)
   implicit none
       type(tSuitcase), intent(in) :: suitcase
       print '(i10,a)', suitcase%socks,'  socks'
       print '(i10,a)', suitcase%shirts,'  shirts'
       print '(i10,a)', suitcase%underwear,'  underwear'
       print '(i10,a)', suitcase%raincoats,'  raincoats'
   end subroutine printSuitcase
end module Luggage
```

and next, the Itinerary module:

```
module Routing
   integer,          parameter :: &
     HOME=1,     MONACO=2,   IBIZA=3,     BIARRITZ=4, &
     nDESTINATIONS=4
   character(len=8), parameter :: destination_names(nDESTINATIONS) = (/ &
     'Home    ', 'Monaco  ', 'Ibiza   ', 'Biarritz' /)
   integer, parameter :: maxTripLen = 100

   type tItinerary
       integer  :: length = 0
       integer  :: destinations(maxTripLen)
   end type tItinerary
contains
   subroutine addDestination(trip,destination)
   implicit none
       type(tItinerary), intent(inout) :: trip
       integer,          intent(in)    :: destination
       if (destination<1 .or. destination>nDESTINATIONS) &
          stop('illegal destination')
       if (trip%length >= maxTripLen) stop('Trip too long')
       trip%length = trip%length + 1
       trip%destinations(trip%length) = destination
   end subroutine AddDestination

   subroutine printItinerary(trip)
   implicit none
       type(tItinerary), intent(in) :: trip
       integer :: i
       if (trip%length==0) then
          print '(a)','        Empty itinerary'
       else
          print '(100(a))','        '//trim(destination_names(trip%destinations(1))), &
             ('-',trim(destination_names(trip%destinations(i))), i=2,trip%length)
       end if
   end subroutine printItinerary
end module Routing
```

Now all I need is a main program:

```
program nestedModule
use travel
implicit none
   type(tTravel) :: plans

   print '(a)','Before planning anything:'
   call printTravel(plans)

   print *
   print '(a)','Planning a trip ... hold on'
   print *
   call addDestination(plans%trip,HOME)
   call addDestination(plans%trip,IBIZA)
   call addDestination(plans%trip,BIARRITZ)
   call addDestination(plans%trip,HOME)

   print '(a)','Now my plans are:'
   Call printTravel(plans)
end program nestedModule
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in my first comment, in the part that you didn't reply to, you can use type extension if you really need the components as actual components of the derived type, not as components of another derived type, so if you want to avoid further structuring the type as a tree.

Note that generally it is not a good idea to have a large flat type, but it as far as I understand it it is what you ask for so here is my answer...

```
module mod1

  type part1
    ...many components
  end type
end module

module mod2
  use mod1
  type, extends(part1) :: part2
    ...many other components
  end type
end module

module the_actual_type_mod
  use mod2
  type, extends(part2) :: the_actual_type
    ...many other components
  end type
end module
```

Another way which was mentioned is `include`. The result is not equivalent but for your purposes almost equivalent

```
module the_actual_type_mod
  use mod2
  type the_type
    include "part1.f90"
    include "part2.f90"
    include "part3.f90"
  end type
end module
```